# Find a document and aggregate a subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The fact that I didn't find documentation on this means that I am probably approaching this the wrong way. Maybe you could help.

I am trying to find all movies where Spielberg was credited.
Easy:

```
Movies.find({credits.who: "Spielberg"}).exec(function....)
```

It returns this:

```
{
    credits: [{
        role: "director",
        who: "Spielberg"
    }, {
        role: "writer",
        who: "Spielberg"
    }],
    title : "The flying unicorn",
    summary: "a unicorn flies"
}
{
    credits: [{
        role: "director",
        who: "someone else"
    }, {
        role: "writer",
        who: "Spielberg"
    }],
    title : "The falling unicorn",
    summary: "a unicorn plumits to its death"
}
```

But I want the result to also have a new entry of aggregated information:

```
{role: "director", #ofCredits: 1}
{role: "writer", #ofCredits: 2}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Tested Works Perfectly Fine:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{$match:{"credits.who":"Spielberg"}},
{$unwind:"$credits"},
{$project:{"credits.role":1,"credits.who":1}},
{"$group":{"_id":{"role":"$credits.role"},"#ofCredits":{"$sum": 1}}}
])
```